# AJAX Редактирование ячейки таблицы в браузере и в БД

Tags: php, html, ajax, input

Хочу сделать чтобы при клике по ячейке таблицы добавлялся временный тег input в который мы вводим новое значение, и при снятии фокуса выполнялся бы ajax. И в случае если запрос был успешным изменить содержимое ячейки в браузере. Передаваемые данные в ajax id тега tr, id тега td и значение введенное в input.

html:

```
<tr id='1'><td id='ip' class='edit'>1231412411</td></tr>
```

ajax:

```
                $('.edit').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).html("<input type='text' value='"+$(this).text()+"'/>");
                }).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }).blur(function(e) {
                    var send_id = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var tag = $(this).attr('id');
                    var info = $(this).text();
                    function funcSuccess(data)
                    {
                        if(data=='ok')
                        {
                            tag.text($(this).val());
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax ({
                        url: "edit.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ({id: send_id, type: tag, value: info}),
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: funcSuccess
                    });
                });
```

и собственно PHP:

```
<?php
include('connect_db.php');
if(isset($_POST['id'])&&isset($_POST['type'])&&isset($_POST['value'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    if(mysql_query ("UPDATE dashboard SET '$type' = '$value' WHERE id = '$id'"))
        echo 'ok';
    }
    else {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

Comment: `$('.edit').click(...).click(...)` ???

Comment: полезно было бы написать, чем Вас не устраивает приведенный код

Comment: @Igor Не устраивает тем, что не получается осуществить задуманное описанное в первом абзаце.  Первый день с AJAX и вообще толком разобраться сложно. В частности застрял на том что в инпут ничего не могу ввести.